# Pumping Lemma for regular languages

Tags: computational-mathematics, regular-language, pumping-lemma

Given is the the following language.

$L= \{ wa^{\vert w \vert} \mid w \in \{a,b\}^* \cup L(b^*a^*)\} $

**Task:** Prove that $L$ is not regular using pumping lemma. 

I am not sure wether I did this correctly. Also I struggle to find the right often failing the first attempt. However I only have arround 15min to complete this prove. Any advice and feedback on how to be more efficient on a pumping lemma proves is greatly appreciated.

**Here is my sollution:** 
Suppose that $w=a^nb^na^{2n}$. As you can see $w\in L$ and $\vert w \vert \ge n.$ 
Decompositions $w=xyz$

1: $x=a^c$ $y=a^d$ $z=a^eb^n a^{2n}$ 
Suppose $i=o$ with $w=a^c(a^d)^i a^eb^n a^{2n}$ 
Since $c+d+e=n$ and $d \ge1$  $ \Rightarrow \vert  a^c a^eb^n \vert \lt 2n$. 
Therefore $w \notin L$ which means L is not regular.

**Why did I choose this word**: 
My thought process was to choose a word that is not in $L(b^*a^*)$ as this part is regular and I would not be able to produce a word that is not in L. But at the same time I needed  a word that is easy to decompose. This is what I struggle with I often need to make  a case distinction to have all the possible decompostions for my word. I started to make my words longer as this reduces the possible decompositions.

**I apologize if this was hard to read my english is bad when it comes to math.**

**Is this prove sufficient?**

Comment: This is fine conceptually. You should add explicitly say that you only consider decompositions with $|xy|\leq n$ and $|y|>0$. Also in the last line of the proof, it should say $xy^0z=a^ca^eb^na^{2n}\notin L$ instead of $w\notin L.$

Comment: Also, the thought process of choosing your word is perfect. In your proof, you might want to add a few explanations as to why you can deduce certain things like the form of the decomposition or why $xz\notin L$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: The definition of $L$ looks wrong. I suppose you mean $L = \{ wa^{\vert w \vert} \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\} \cup b^*a^*$

Comment: This was given to us like this. But i was wondering about this aswell. There should be a different sign for the first L. What they mean is the Language that is created by the reg ex $b^*a^*$

Comment: This is not the main point. The main point is that $\{a,b\}^* \cup L(b^*a^*) = \{a, b\}^*$, which means that the last } is misplaced.